# how to do sphinx tree and subtree structure like link from md file

Tags: python-sphinx

My project structure like

[image: folder like]

Then it should generate html page like

[image: render html looks like]

How can we do that in Sphinx?

Comment: What have you tried? Please explain what the problem is and how we can reproduce it.

Comment: @mzjn Thank you, I am trying to create a document generated from .md file with having category or subcategory like structure based on different MD file

Comment: @mzjn i need some example